# Android: align checkbox-rectangle with text underneath it

Tags: android, checkbox, android-linearlayout

I have a `Checkbox` with a `TextView` below, this looks like the following:

[image]

How can I align the left side of Lorem with the left side of the checkbox?

My layout-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/letter_standard_padding">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/mobile_text_module_checkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textColor="@color/abo_accent"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="@style/AboLetterText" />

        <ImageButton
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/contract_check"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content_text_view"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textAppearance="@style/AboLetterText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem seems to be that the checkbox itself is bigger than the rectangle:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have used negative margin:

```
android:layout_marginLeft = "-4dp"
```

it has worked in the devices I tested but you have to test it too.  
or set margin to the TextView:

```
android:layout_marginLeft = "4dp"
```

Comment: It is always around 6dp, but then you can't see the whole shape of the checkbox

Comment: weird... with `-7dp` I still see the whole shape, only with `-8dp` it starts disappearing...

Comment: You have to keep in mind that you may also want a descent ripple effect when clicked so keep it low